# C# VS incompatibility with versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I just can't figure out why is this happening , and I don't know what have changed, but as of last week , every project (a working project) I open in VS generates many errors such as :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

It even happens when I simply download projects from GIT such as [Sieve pagination](https://github.com/Biarity/Sieve) , which is probably working  .

I'm guessing it's some setting I need to set or files I have to delete, but couldn't find what am I suppose to do..

I would appreciate some help ..

**EDIT:** Every thing seems like its broken , a simple `using` is being marked in red ->u`sing Microsoft.AspNetCore;` says it doesn't exists in namespace Microsoft` . Or even string are being marked with red .

Comment: The error message seems to tell you what your issue is? Do you realise maybe that .net core and .net standard are different things?

Comment: @Liam This is a project from my prudoction . It works! .Only on my local storage it doesn't

Comment: @sagi Does it works with a plain `dotnet run` command ?

Comment: Mmm, never tried that .. do you mean to run dotnet run in the main folder? If so, then it doesn’t work . still throws errors @itminus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be an issue with your version of Visual studio. I had the same issue with an earlier version when opening .Net Core 2.1 projects and updated to Visual studio 2017 15.8.2 and this action helped resolving the errors you are talking about.

Comment: That's just what I was doing , my current version is 15.0. I'll update if it helped when the update finish .

Comment: Yes, that was the problem .